# Cannot update embeded excel links in powerpoint to a different sheet

Tags: excel, powerpoint, excel-2010

I have monthly report data in separate tabs, Jan to Dec.

I took the data from Jan and linked it to a powerpoint page in order to display it for briefings. I have the layout set exactly how I want it, so I copied the slide and then wanted to edit the new slide to use the data from Feb instead of Jan, however I can't seem to update the links so they use the other sheet. It just asks me to select a new file.

The links option allows me to select a new spreadsheet file but not the same file and different sheet. Is there anyway around this?

The data embedded in the ppt is both cell data & charts.

Hopefully, I've explained what I mean well enough.

Many thanks for any help and advice. =)

Answer (score 0):

Your subject mentions links but later you say "The data embedded in the ppt ..."

Linked and embedded objects are two different things with different behaviors.

If you want different slides to point to different parts of your worksheet/workbook and to update at need, you'll want to do this for each slide:

Select the data in Excel
Copy it
Switch to PowerPoint, move to the slide where you want to display the data
Choose Paste Special, then choose to Link

You could, in theory, accomplish something similar by creating one link, then copying the slide and finally editing the link target, but that'd take either an add-in or some coding, and would in any case probably be more trouble than it'd be worth.

Answer (score 0):

Create a tab in the file and name it "Current" or something to that effect.
Link it to the month tab you want, like Jan.
Create the link in powerpoint how ever you have already, to this tab and not the Jan tab.
you can change the links in the tab "Current" to point to a different tab, like Mar.
Update you powerpoint by either up dating links (for pastespecial as link ) or just double click the embedded object in powerpoint while the Excel file is already open